# GoogleTV jquery UI library reference

Tags: jquery, google-tv

I'm working on a googletv optimized food ordering web app. I've found the jquery library reference and keyboard navigation reference on the google developer site, but neither of them just provide a working demo of a regular web page with keyboard navigation enabled. Could somebody here provide me with a demo (or link to a demo) of a web page with different navigable keyzones using the google tv ui jquery library? None of the default controls (rowcontrol, rotatorcontrol, etc) provided in the demos are appropriate for my app, I just need to create a regular page with keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you are after - the jquery demo code for Google TV does the job though you will have to take a bit of a deep dive to figure out how to extract the keyboard controls. Have you looked at the closure code?

If you are looking for a tutorial on how to incorporate keyboard navigation into your web app you may want to check out: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/adding-keyboard-navigation/ which I believe could lead you where you want with your application.

Answer (score 1):

Both of our [standard templates](https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/ajax_gtv_templates_tutorial#templates) use the jQuery library.